# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) in Fortran 90

Tags: compilation, segmentation-fault, fortran

I'm writing a Fortran 90 code (below) and I get a segfault (core dumped) error. What is Core Dumped and how do I fix it?

```
program make_pict
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: REAL8=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,300)
    INTEGER, SAVE :: nstp,npr,step
    REAL(REAL8), SAVE :: r 
    REAL(REAL8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE, SAVE ::  f,fa
    INTEGER :: xw,yw,x,y
    REAL:: ax,ay
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(250000) ::  pxa
    REAL(REAL8) :: s,s2 
    LOGICAL, SAVE :: initialized=.FALSE.

    WRITE(*,*) 'give values ax,ay'
    READ(*,*) ax,ay
    xw = 256
    yw = 256

    OPEN(1,FILE='picture.pxa')

    do x=0, xw-1
        do y=0, yw-1
            f(x,y)=(765./2)*(ax*(1-cos(2*3.14159*x*(1.0/xw)))+ay(1+cos(2*3.14159*y*(1.0/yw))))
        end do
    end do

    WRITE(1,'(2I6)') xw,yw
    ALLOCATE(f(0:xw-1,0:yw-1),fa(0:xw-1,0:yw-1))
    DO y=0,yw-1
    WRITE(1,'(256I4)') (f(x,y),x=0,xw-1)
    END DO
    CLOSE(1)     
    initialized=.TRUE.

    step=0
    nstp=100
end program make_pict
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to set `f` before it's allocated. You need the allocate statement before the double loop which sets it! One way to solve this problem yourself is to put output statements everywhere, which would pinpoint the location of the error.

Some other problems I noticed:

- You're missing a `*` in `ay(`. I'm surprised this code compiled for you, actually.
- Why are you using such a low-precision value for `pi`? You're requesting precision to the 15th decimal but your value for `pi` only goes to 6?
- What is the purpose of step, nstp, and initialized? I guess they're for features to be implemented? You should strive to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Adding the save attribute doesn't do anything here. You should read about what it actually does, but it's typically not needed. In a program it definitely does nothing.

To answer your second question, segfaults can occur for many reasons. Core dumped only refers to the system's handling of the segmentation fault. There are many causes of segmentation faults; attempting to access an unallocated array is one of them.

Comment: I would add that some compiler flags can be really useful in debugging this sort of issues. For gfortran, I would start with `-g -Wall -fcheck=all`